# JQuery ui error when using variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement a js price slider.

```
function initSliders(){
    $("#price_slider").slider({
        min: 10.08,
        max: 562.99,
        values:[10.08, 562.99],
        step: 10.00,
        range:true,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
          $("#price_range_label" ).html(ui.values[ 0 ] + ' - ' + ui.values[ 1 ]);
          $('#price_filter').val(ui.values[0] + '-' + ui.values[1]).trigger('change');
        }
    });
});
```

This code works just fine and as intended. However, if I try to use variables (get the actual min and max from a db) for the exact same values,

```
 function initSliders(pricemin, pricemax){
    $("#price_slider").slider({
        min: pricemin,
        max: pricemax,
        values:[pricemin, pricemax],
        step: 10.00,
        range:true,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
          $("#price_range_label" ).html(ui.values[ 0 ] + ' - ' + ui.values[ 1 ]);
          $('#price_filter').val(ui.values[0] + '-' + ui.values[1]).trigger('change');
        }
    });
});
```

I get a console error and the slide points refuse to move:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined      jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js:7
```

I'm very new to javascript, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or what's going on here.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/5efcnp9u/1/ For some reason, I couldn't get partfilter() function in the fiddle, it wouldnt work.

Comment: Are you able to create an [example](http://jsfiddle.net) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Ok, first you said `toFixed` undefined, now you're saying `addClass`, neither of which are in your code - we can't guess, please post ALL your code or create a fiddle

Comment: @DarrenSweeney It was `toFixed`, that was with jquery-ui 1.11.4. I reverted back to the one I was using, 1.10.2, and that's now the error I get. I'll try to put a fiddle together.

Comment: Fiddle added to question, also here: https://jsfiddle.net/5efcnp9u/1/